# How to attribute existing colnames to a new matrix/dataframe

Tags: r, matrix

We have a matrix W and a list of 2500 matrices B, each matrice B (from 1 to 2500) has different column names (chr [1..80]).

- W (nrow=100000, ncol=80)
- each matrix B (nrow=1000, ncol=80)

For each element of this list, we have to create the same matrix W (that we already have) BUT with the corresponding B col names.

Comment: We can use `Map`, i.e.  `Map(function(x,y) {colnames(x) <- y; x}, replicate(length(lst), W, simplify=FALSE), lapply(B, colnames))`

Answer (score 0):

We can `replicate` the 'W' matrix to a `list` of 'W' matrices with length of the `list` equal to the `length` of `list` of 'B' matrices i.e. 'lst'.  We extract the column names from each 'B' matrix in 'lst' using `lapply`.  Then, pass these two as arguments to `Map` and assign the column names of the `list` of 'W' matrices with the corresponding `list` of column names.

```
res <-  Map(function(x,y) {
         colnames(x) <- y
         x}, replicate(length(lst), W, simplify=FALSE),
          lapply(B, colnames))

lapply(res, head, 2)
#[[1]]
#    A  B  C  D  E
#[1,] 1 21 41 61 81
#[2,] 2 22 42 62 82

#[[2]]
#    F  G  H  I  J
#[1,] 1 21 41 61 81
#[2,] 2 22 42 62 82
```

and the column names of 'B' matrices in 'lst' is

```
lapply(lst, colnames)
#[[1]]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

#[[2]]
#[1] "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

NOTE: Here I used a small dataset with 5 columns for 'B' and 'W' matrix and a `list` of length 2.

#### data

```
lst <- list(matrix(1:25, ncol=5, dimnames=list(NULL, 
   LETTERS[1:5])), matrix(26:50, ncol=5, 
      dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[6:10]))) 
W <- matrix(1:100, ncol=5)
```

Comment: Sorry but we can’t seem to make it work. here is a more detailed explanation of our problem: we have a list « B » with each element B[i] (i 1:2500 ) being a matrix. For each matrix B[i] we want to extract its colnames (different for each i)  and plug it to W. Thus creating a list of 2500 matrices W[i] with each W being equal but having the corresponding colnames of B[i]

Comment: @marie-odile28  This is based on your description and I added some data based on that.  It works for me.  The `list` object is `lst`.  It could be `B` for you.

Comment: @marie-odile28  You can check my example and the output.  It does what you described.  BTW, you haven't provided any reproducible example.